# HttpPost method is not fired if the submit button is disabled

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a view as follows: DemoView.cshtml

```
@model Mvc3Razor.Models.UserModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<h2>
    Create</h2>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>UserModel</legend>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.City)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.City)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.City)
        </div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" /></p>
    </fieldset>
}
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('input[type="submit"]').click(function () {
            $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        });
    });
</script>
```

And a controller: HomeController.cs

```
[HttpPost]
        public ViewResult Create(UserModel um)
        {
            if (!TryUpdateModel(um))
            {
                ViewBag.updateError = "Create Failure";
                return View(um);
            }

            _usrs.Create(um);
            return View("Details", um);

        }
```

In order to prevent multiple button clicks, I am trying to disable the button once user clicks the Create button but once the Create button is disabled it is not firing the HttpPost method.

Can anyone help me out in order to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 4):

Try disabling the button when the form is submitted and not when the submit button is clicked:

```
$("form").submit(function() {
    $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
    return true;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What I will suggest  is to redirect user back to Index Page  upon Successfull Post. You want use [PRG Pattern](http://www.eworldui.net/blog/post/2008/05/ASPNET-MVC---Using-Post2c-Redirect2c-Get-Pattern.aspx)

> [Post, Redirect, Get (PRG) pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) in which it is "to help avoid
>   duplicate form submissions and allow web applications to behave more
>   intuitively with browser bookmarks and the reload button"

```
usrs.Create(um);
//Redirect to Index Page here
```

see this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7940939/mvc3-model-validation-best-practice-redirect-after-post-state-change) for more details