# AddModelError message not showing up

Tags: asp.net-mvc, exception

I have a EDIT page, and when user submits the page by entering same name, exception is raised and getting caught. But its not redirecting to edit page to display the model error instead displaying asp.net yellow error page with exception details.I still don't have any code in controller's OnException and I am see this on my dev machine.

```
try
{
 //code
}
catch (Exception ex)
{                
   ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Customer with same name already exists.");
}

return RedirectToAction("Edit", new {id=model.id}); <--not executing
```

Comment: Can you post what is on the "yellow screen of death"?

Comment: I know this exception but my aim here is to display friendly error message on the screen. Anyways, its unique key DB exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yahooo!! I figured out what was the issue. Actually I was doing trans.commit and when it fails, I am not doing rollback in the catch block. Thanks all for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you passing 'String.Empty' as Key in AddModelError..then In your view you should have ..

The error message present in the

```
<%: Html.ValidationSummary() %>
```

or 
If you want to specify 'Name' as a Key then

```
ModelState.AddModelError(Name, "Customer with same name already exists.");  

<%=Html.TextBox("Name") %> <br /> 
<%=Html.ValidationMessage("Name") %>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the Validation Error message you are adding in your action method in the view, you need to return the model to view. You will do the Redirect to the GET action, when your Save is successfully completed.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateUser(UserViewModel model)
{
  try
  {
     //Save and Redirect to GET action (PRG pattern)
     //Assuming model.ID will have the Id of record.

    return RedirectToAction("View",new {id=model.ID });
  }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {
    //Log error 
    ModelState.AddModelError("","Some error message");
  }
  return View(model);
}
```

Comment: I am using PRG pattern described in below link and I am passing model to the get action. Model properties error messages are showing up but not this exception friendly message.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7940939/mvc3-model-validation-best-practice-redirect-after-post-state-change

Comment: @Sundeep do you have `@Html.ValidationSummary(true)` inside your `form` to show the not property bound error messages ?

Comment: @nemesv, Yes,I have it. I dont think it is reaching till that point.

Comment: i think you are getting an exception in your GET method. put try catch   in that and use breakpoints to see what is wrong. btw, Passing a  complex model to a GET action is not sticking with PRG. Remember HTTP is stateless.