# Pattern or way of working with action consulting and action results

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a form with various values ​​to enter by the user, then the user sends the query and processes the search for result.

This is pretty simple, but the problem is this.

In MVC if the form has errors, to do validation on the server should show the form again with errors. but if I send my request to the data search action, I should come back with a redirect to the consultation action form and this would lose validation messages.

Currently we do is request the data to the action of the consultation form and then if everything is fine, we redirect action result sending the data of request with tempdata.

Is there any better way for this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, PRG pattern should work in your case. In post operation, if modelstate is invalid, redirect back to consultation form otherwise proceed with search operation. The filters will internally save the errors in tempdata.

[MVC3 model validation best practice redirect after post / state change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7940939/mvc3-model-validation-best-practice-redirect-after-post-state-change)

Answer (score 0):

Return either `View(model)` with validation errors or `RedirectToAction()` depending on the ModelState:

```
ActionResult Consult(@params) {
    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
        //validation succeeded.
        return RedirectToAction("SearchResults", {searchParams = @params});
    }

    return View(@params);
}
```

Point is, you can pass parameters when redirecting.

Comment: ok, that explain what we are doing now, the question is whether there is any pattern or different model to do so because we do not like doing the redirect or display results with the same URL consultation

Comment: Basically, you have a non-standard scenario, because usually search form (or the form collecting search params) is on the same page (view) as the results are. In that case, you could either return a validation exception or the search results (or both) at the same time. But since you have this special situation, you must handle what you have.